# How do I sort MySQL results by 2 different variations of sorting?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Firstly, I apologize for the poor question title, I can't quite explain what my problem is, but I'm sure that an experienced MySQL user will know.

After querying the database to retrieve a specific set of customers, they are originally sorted by the "completed" column, with values of "0" and "1".

I would like to sort all customers with the value "0" by delivery date ASC and, all customers with the value "1" by delivery date DESC.

Here is my first and only failed attempt:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (completed='0' ORDER BY delivery ASC) AND (completed='1' ORDER BY delivery DESC)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What's the type of column `delivery`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done using `case-when` in the `order by` clause as

```
SELECT * FROM users   
order by 
case 
 when completed='0' then delivery
end,
case 
 when completed='1' then delivery
end desc;
```

If you need to send all `completed='0'` on the top assuming there is no null values then you can do as

```
order by 
completed,
case 
  when completed='0' then delivery
end,
case 
  when completed='1' then delivery
end desc;
```

Comment: This nearly works! But it does not show the completed 0's first?

Comment: @CraigyCraigo just add `order by completed, case ...`

Answer (score 1):

The first sorting field is `completed` `ASC`-ending, of course.

For the second field you can use an expression that makes the values of `delivered` to be sorted as desired. Assuming the type of column `delivered` is `DATE` or `DATETIME`, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(delivered)` is a number.

For `completed = '0'` use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(delivered)` in the ascending order. For `completed <> '0'` using the negated value (`- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(delivered)`) also sorted `ASC`-ending will reverse the order of the rows.

This is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY completed ASC,
  CASE 
    WHEN completed = '0' THEN   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(delivered)       # ASC-ending
    ELSE                      - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(delivered)       # DESC-ending
  END ASC
;
```

Comment: Interesting alternative but I think the answer above is easier to understand and use.

Comment: Indeed, it's more clear and it works no matter the type of column `delivered`. Mine does not work for strings.